# PostgreSQL User Authorization/Configuration Issues

Tags: users, postgresql

I've installed postgresql 9.3, but can't get any users authorized. I also can't use initdb or pg_ctl. I can't find pg_hba.conf either.

Comment: Can you provide to us examples of commands you've used?  Any documentation you're following?

Comment: I agree with @earthmeLon, please say what you've tried so far, etc.  But also, read my answer, as I try and answer some of your questions/concerns below.

Answer (score 0):

**Where the `pg_hba.conf` file resides:**

`pg_hba.conf` is in `/etc/postgresql/X.Y/main/` (where `X.Y` is your version, 9.3 for you, 9.4 for me).

---

**"Missing" programs:**

`pg_ctl` may not be installed by default. `initdb` may also not be installed by default.  Both are installable by `postgres-xc`.

---

**Adding users so they can be authorized:**

You'll have to add a user/role in via the `psql` command line client.  You'll then have to add the user to `pg_hba.conf`.

I suggest using `pgadmin3`, a graphical interface/program, to work with user roles and adding them.  It allows you to specifically select the individual permissions you want to give a user globally (which should usually be no special permissions, just to create the user, and give permissions for a given DB separately).

---

**Configuring `pg_hba.conf`**

This can be a little tricky.  Once you've got a user login role, you need to add them to `pg_hba.conf`.  The format of the file is [fully explained in detail in the PosgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).  A short summary is here.

Unless there is a matching line here, the default access rule is "deny access".

This is the format of a `pg_hba.conf` line:

```
TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD
```

`type` is the type of connection.  Local connections from the same computer get the `local` type.  Connections from a non-local IP (i.e. over TCP) get the `host` type.  `hostnossl` can be used instead, and will identify any network connection to it (i.e. non-local) that is not over SSL.  `hostssl` can be used to specify any network connection that is over SSL, however it is not default to have SSL set up.

`database` is self-explanatory - what database do you want to set these access permissions/restrictions to.  A special database type is `all` which indicates all databases.

`user` is the username / role that you've added to Postgres.  It has to exist within postgres, and it may need to exist as a local system user (however that's explained in where I explain `METHOD`).

`ADDRESS` is an IPv4 or IPv6 address or range.  It is only to be used when `host`, `hostnossl`, or `hostssl` are specified under `type`.  It can be a CIDR range or an individual IP address.

`METHOD` is how to handle authentication.

- For a local user with the `local` type, it should be `peer` authentication, or `md5` authentication if you want the user to be able to login from a different local computer user account with a password.
- For a `host`, `hostssl`, or `hostnossl` connection type, you probably want to use `md5` here, however you may have other types of authentication (see the documentation link above).
- ***Under no circumstances unless you are insane or really know what you are doing should you use the `trust` method.***  This has ***zero*** authentication of the person and is a security hole from Hell, even for `local` type connections.

I advise you to read through the linked documentation on the `pg_hba.conf` file, it's a better explanation of things.

Comment: I can't get psql to do anything, so I'm looking for another way to add a user. 'pgadmin3' looks neat but I can't get the psql console plugin working, maybe because I haven't linked it to pgadmin3.

Comment: Thomas W. thanks for your response.  I did edit the pg_hba.conf file to set local authentication to md5, but no behavior change - I stll can't log in. Postgres-xc installation wanted to remove every postgre instance installed in ordered to work - I'm not that brave.

Comment: @BrianCady yeah that's why it's not installed by default.  Did you create the login role for the user inside postgres yet?  You actually have to *create* the user with password inside of postgres, either via `pgadmin3` or `psql` directly.  Then reload the postgresql config (`sudo service postgresql reload`) or restart the postgres instance (`sudo service postgresql restart`).  Don't forget that last step - you *have* to refresh the config to get the pg_hba.conf changes.

Comment: I've tried to create the user with pgadmin3 (failed - no psql console) and with psql (failed -ident  authentication error). I tried as both postgre, the non-root user I set up a system account for, and as briancady101, the admin account. I finally got pg_hba.conf edited, changing peer to md5 for user postgre.

Comment: Does it matter that I have both postgresql  8.4 and 9.3 installed?

Comment: @BrianCady Yes, actually, it does.  First, verify that you have `psql` installed (`postgresql-X.Y-client`).  Secondly, verify that pgAdmin3 is actually using it.  Then try and manage the server (with the postgres user and the password).  Since you edited `pg_hba.conf` make sure to refresh the configuration.  Then you have to go in and *add* the user.  When then having clients connect they may need to use a different port or specify the postgres instance to use, I'm not 100% certain about that one and I'll get back to you

Comment: I can't verify that postgresql-9.3-client exists, nor is installed on my Ubuntu linux machine. No package in Ubuntu software centre, nothing found with 'sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-client'. I couldn't find it in  a web search either. - edit - postgresql-client-9.3 is installed.

Comment: pgsdmin3 has no plugins installed. PSQL-Console shows up as an unavailable option.

Comment: psql (Postgresql ) 9.3.9 is installed

Comment: " Then try and manage the server (with the postgres user and the password). <snip> Then you have to go in and add the user." Can I just use the postgres user 'postgres'? But when I try to install postgresql user 'postgres' I get 'Ident authorization failure' even though I am not signed up at pg_hba.conf to use ident.